# Retrieve domain from wildcard URI

Tags: c#, .net

I need a suggestion on how could I retrieve the domain from the following :

- *.yahoo.co.uk
- *.yahoo.com

so, in both cases, my method must return yahoo.co.uk and yahoo.com.

Is there an easy way to do this, or I just have to struggle with strings and counting characters from the "." and stuff like that?

Thank you in advance.

Regards,

Andrei

Comment: a) in what language? b) what are the **exact** rules for wildcards in your domain name patterns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TrimStart if you are lokking for stripping just the '.' and '*' characters:

```
String testString = "*.yahoo.co.uk";
Console.WriteLine(testString.TrimStart(new char[]{'.','*'}));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (s.StartsWith("*.")) s = s.Substring(2)
```